# Using bar_index as length for other highest()

Tags: pine-script

i running into some issues while using bar_index stored in variable to calculate the highest() in a range.

In my study i store the bar_index into a global variable `f_barindex_enter := bar_index` when i enter a position. After leaving the position i'm trying to retrieve the highest price between enter and exit `f_barindex_distance = bar_index[0] - f_barindex_enter` for further use in my study.

What i found is that when using `highest(f_barindex_distance)` generates a error when i apply the study on a chart. Pinescript help says that bar_index returns a integer but doesn't seem to work with highest(). I also tried to 'force' convert the variable to a integer by using int() but also generates a error.

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not protecting `highest()` against all eventualities. See this example taken from [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-calculate-values-depending-on-variable-lengths-that-reset-on-a-condition):

```
//@version=4
study("Lowest low since condition", "", true)
cond = rising(close, 3)
lookback = int(max(1, nz(barssince(cond)) + 1))
lowestSinceCondition = lowest(lookback)
plot(lowestSinceCondition)
// Show when condition occurs.
plotchar(cond, "cond", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// Display varying lookback period in Data Window.
plotchar(lookback, "lookback", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.